# Azure Stack REST APIs

Tags: azure-stack

We are looking for Azure stack Resource REST APIs. we want to handle Azure stack Resources like Resource groups, Virtual machines, Vnet, Subnet, etc. using REST APIs, can anyone point us to any link or document so where we can get all these APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azurestack/vm-extensions/create) documentation , for Azure Stack Admin Rest API's.

Here is the sample Rest API , that can be used to list all the Compute operations in Azure Stack.

```
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Compute.Admin/operations?api-version=2015-12-01-preview
```

You can also refer these documentations, How to [Make a REST API requests to Azure Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-rest-api-use?view=azs-2005) & also about [interacting with Azure Stack Hub Rest API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-stack-blog/interacting-with-azure-stack-hub-rest-api/ba-p/1737472).